# Изменение доступного количества товара в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите хочу массово изменить доступное количество товара, знаю как сделать поштучно, но если мне надо весь инфоблок=18, то как это сделать?

```
Cmodule::IncludeModule('catalog');
$PRODUCT_ID = 16917; // id товара
$arFields = array('QUANTITY' => 1000);
CCatalogProduct::Update($PRODUCT_ID, $arFields);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получать все ID товаров и в цикле каждому менять. Массового обновления нет, потому что при обновлении каждого товара запускаются события, которые поддерживают целостность и консистентность.

Если будет просто SQL запрос на обновление всех записей, то невозможно запустить события на каждый отдельный товар - тут может поломаться какая-то логика

Answer (score 0):

Если количество меньше необходимого ("<CATALOG_QUANTITY"), то задаем его в размере $quantity для инфоблока $iblock_id по $elements_per_request элементов за запрос.

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
Cmodule::IncludeModule('catalog');

$iblock_id = 12;
$quantity = 1000;
$elements_per_request = 500;

$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "CATALOG_QUANTITY");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock_id, "<CATALOG_QUANTITY" => $quantity);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => $elements_per_request), $arSelect);

while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = array('QUANTITY' => $quantity);
    CCatalogProduct::Update($ob->fields["ID"], $arFields);
}
?>
```